# Using a model as a frontend for a dao

Tags: java, model, dao, frontend

Say I use a simple frontend for information passed on by a DAO that uses JDBC (without ORM). In other words, the class would have no attributes to speak of. Would this considered as a valid approach? What issues could it potentially cause and how could a class be designed to avoid them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to the data transfer object pattern. So long as the pattern fits your needs, it is a valid approach. I'm not aware of any pitfalls as such.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object
- http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/TransferObject.html

Comment: I'm using simple business objects. As a DAO already returns these, the model can get return values directly from the DAO and modify them if necessary.